# Do xrumer drip link blasts work?

Tags: blackhat

I've heard of these so called services where I can get 100 backlinks built everyday from web profiles etc via a software called Xrumer running on the servers.

What is the benefit of getting 100 backlinks everyday when Google's algorithm takes account link velocity? Won't google easily see this kind of suspicious backlink building?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xrumer gets garbage links. Even if there isn't such a thing as link velocity (and I don't personally believe there is) the links that software gets won't make any kind of difference in a page's rankings. Quality links is what webmasters want. Not garbage easy to grab links that aren't relevant or valuable in any other way.

Comment: ah, so there is no link velocity?

Comment: I don't believe there is. But there is such a thing then there won't be a penalty for it as it would be too easy to hit a competitor with it.

Comment: There's no way to definitively answer "link velocity". But Google could certainly graph out whatever they want, and hugs spikes or particular patterns certainly could indicate artificiality (when combined with looking at the types of sites linking in)